# How to disable (cleanly) the power button?

Tags: systemd

Systemd is configured by default to shutdown the computer when the power button is pressed. I want to keep this behavior, unless when my user is logged. When I'm logged in, I want to open a shutdown dialog instead of immediately shutting down.

I have achieved to disable `systemd`'s handling using `systemd-inhibit` in a user service that starts when I log in and stops when I log out. This method works well, except that I have an idle thread for the call to `sleep 1000d` open all the time.

For cleanliness, I'm looking for a way to achieve this without the sleeping thread, which I find very annoying when I look at my `htop`.

Here is my user service:

```
[Unit]
Description=User daemon to disable systemd's handling of the power button

[Service]
ExecStart=nohup systemd-inhibit \
                --what="handle-power-key" \
                --who="disable-shutdown-button script" \
                --why="allows i3 to open shutdown-dialog instead" \
                sleep 1000d

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**Edit:** login is done through `lightdm` display manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the `systemd-inhibit` command a separate user service, you might want to prefix it to the command that starts `i3` or otherwise is essential to your GUI login session.

`systemd-inhibit` was designed to require a command to run it with, because the intent was to provide a way to inhibit things like suspend/hibernate/shutdown for the duration of specific tasks, like a package manager running a critical system update task, or burning an optical media, etc. That way, the inhibition can automatically end when the task that needed it ends or is aborted for any reason.

Adding `systemd-inhibit` to your session start-up that way can seem redundant because `systemd`/`logind` will track the processes belonging to your session via control groups, but that's the only way I see to make the usage pattern fit without requiring a dummy `sleep` command or similar.

---

In the comments you mentioned you use `lightdm`. It normally runs `lightdm-session` as the `session-wrapper` script. You could modify this script, or place an override file like this to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/`. You can choose the name for yourself, but it should have the suffix `.conf`:

```
[Seat:*]
session-wrapper=/usr/local/bin/shutdown-button-inhibit
```

And the `/usr/local/bin/shutdown-button-inhibit` script could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(whoami) = "Julien" ]  # edit this to match your username
then
    exec systemd-inhibit \
        --what="handle-power-key" \
        --who="shutdown-button-inhibit script" \
        --why="allows i3 to open shutdown-dialog instead" \
        lightdm-session "$@"
else
    exec lightdm-session "$@"
fi
```

You should set this script executable, with `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/shutdown-button-inhibit`.

Using `exec` makes the script interpreter replace itself with `lightdm-session` instead of hanging around as one more process.

If your `lightdm` configuration is already customized to invoke something other than `lightdm-session`, then you'll have to edit this script to match.

Comment: I use `lightdm` as display manager, is there any way to have it wrap the call to `i3` only for a specific user?

Comment: See my edited answer above.

Comment: I think it'd be better to use a group to disable the power button for any user in the group `disable-powerbutton` or similar. Thank you for the edit and detailed instructions, answer accepted.

Comment: Sure, just replace the test in the `if [ ... ]` with a test for membership in a particular group and you've got it.